# Translating English Language into Formulae of Sentential Logic in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic, formula, truthtable

I have a set of approximately 30 rules in English sentences that determine whether hours worked are Standard, Over-Time or Double-Time.

I need to take a table of employee total hours in a day and split them accordingly by Standard, Over-Time or Double-Time base on which Union the employee belongs to.

I was thinking that if I could convert the English Rules into Formulae of Sentential Logic, that I could then create a Truth Table to pass the employee rows through to determine which hours are Standard, Over-Time or Double-Time.

Does anyone have any ideas/samples how I can accomplish this task? I am open to all suggestions.

All responses are appreciated,
Mike

Below is a sample rule and a sample rows;

1. Rule: ST paid for all hours worked within scheduled shift
2. Rows:

Data Rows:

```
id      create_date         last_update         created_by  last_updated_by     deleted_by  WORKORDERNUMBER     NAME        EMPLOYEENUMBER      TIMEIN          TIMEOUT
177     7/16/2014 17:50     7/16/2014 17:50     5           5                   0           167320002           Joe Doe     56                  7/16/2014 1:23  7/16/2014 3:23
178     7/16/2014 17:50     7/16/2014 12:21     5           5                   0           167320002           Joe Doe2    137                 7/16/2014 1:23  7/16/2014 3:23
179     7/16/2014 17:50     7/16/2014 12:21     5           5                   0           167320002           Joe Doe3    108                 7/16/2014 1:23  7/16/2014 3:23
```

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information to offer much help here. We need ddl (create table) and sample data (inserts), or alternately a sqlfiddle. Then an explanation of what you expect as output and why.

Comment: This is a monstrous task to undertake in tsql.  I used to work for a software company that made time & attendance software.  They employed a senior developer whose only job was to create/enhance/maintain the "payroll rules" of the software.  You mentioned "Standard, Over-Time, or Double-Time"...My former company supported more than 100 different categories.  Back then, the logic was written in C (later migrated to VB6, I think) and handled from the client apps.  I would strongly consider a CLR function (server-side) for this type of processing.

Comment: DMason, the reason to accomplish in SQL is that all the Emp Time Rows above come from time collection app in the field from all mobile devices to Mobile Database and then are Pulled from Mobile Database into SAP Database. The process has to happen in Proc/Func/Trig each night so that the following morning Payroll can approve or not approve ST/OT/DT pay. It is nice to know you understand what I am trying to do. Thanks for your response, any ideas?

Comment: Thanks Siyual, for making the rows look pretty.

Comment: Mike, surely SAP has an API you can use for this type of import.  Right?

Comment: DMason, I have built an Add-On using the SAP API that integrates into the SAP App interface. Are you suggesting I use the API to be able to bring this issue outside of the SQL realm and use VB or C# to handle this? If so, can you describe a high level, basic design so I can picture in my mind? Thanks, you have been a tremendous help by getting me to think outside the box, Mike

Comment: I'm thinking you would write a VB or C# app (whatever language you like that supports SAP's API).  The app would pull the data from the mobile db (probably as an ado recordset).  Iterate through the recordset rows and call some as yet to be discovered API function and pass in the recordset row values as params to the function.  From there, the API handles all the logic and decides if the time worked is Standard, OT, Double-Time, etc.  SAP should make the API continue to function with future versions of their software.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish my task by;

1. Creating a table that holds the Rules, in addition to the Formulae of Sentential Logic.
2. I created another table to hold unique schedules by Union Local, Local Schedule, AppliedRules
3. A Function that selects all applied rules Formulas per Local employee ID, in return Table I cycle and validate variables that represent every variation of Formula parts.
4. A Procedure that cycles all the records of time entries and gathers addition data necessary for Function, Inserted Split rows etc...

This solution works perfectly and allows easy addition of rules by adding the rule in English and the associated Formula of Sentential Logic to the Rules Table.

DMason was a huge inspiration on getting me to think out of the box. Thanks DMason!